# How to change style of the text blocks in divs when they don't have specific tag name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list which consists of multiple divs for sections and spans for units groups and classes. Before every divs and spans I use image with an arrow to expand list and a styled checkbox input
I don't want text to wrap around image when the whole text string can't fit in one line. 
I need it to align vertically at the same point where the first line of text was but not to the image.

Can't use span in front of text because I have a long list of items and I use DOM with span to toggle list. 
And text is not inside label tags because I am using this for styling checkboxes.

Is there any way around this? Maybe using jquery DOM selectors and making display block? But I can't seem to target correctly and not really applying correct styling:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sections label').nextSibling.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'background-color': 'red',
        'margin-left': '5px'
    });
});
```

```css
 .sections {
     display: block;
     width:100%;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-right: 0;
 }
 .units {
     display: block;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-left: 15px;
 }
 .groups {
     display: block;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-left: 15px;
 }
 .classes {
     display: block;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-left: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sections" id="SectionA">
    <a><img src="images/arrow_plus.png"></a>
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="A" value="A" />
    <label for="A"></label>
    Section A ClothesSection A ClothesSection A ClothesSection A ClothesSection A ClothesSection A Clothes 
    <span class="units" id="01units ">
        <a><img src="images/arrow_plus.png"></a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="ckeck01" value="01"/>
        <label for="01">01</label> 
        Dresses
  <span class="groups" id="01\.1hide">
      01.1 Summer dresses
            <span class="classes" id="01\.11hide">
                <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="01\.11" value="01.11"/>
                <label for="01.11"></label>
                AAAA0001 
            </span>
         <span class="classes" id="01\.12hide">
                <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="01\.11" value="01.12"/>
                <label for="01.12"></label>
                AAAA0002 
            </span>
        </span> 
        <span class="groups" id="01\.2hide">
         01.2 Winter dresses
            <span class="classes" id="01\.20hide">
                <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="01\.20" value="01.20"/>
                <label for="01.20"></label>
                AAAA0003AAAA0003AAAA0003AAAA0003AAAA0003AAAA0003AAAA0003 
            </span>
         <span class="classes" id="01\.21hide">
                <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="01\.21" value="01.21"/>
                <label for="01.21"></label> 
                AAAA0004
            </span>
        </span> 
        <span class="groups" id="01\.3hide">
            01.3 Prom dresses
        </span>
    </span> 
    <span class="units" id="02units">
        <a><img src="images/arrow_plus.png"></a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="regular-checkbox" id="ckeck02" value="02"/>
        <label for="02"></label>
        02 Skirts
        <span class="groups" id="02\.1hide">
            01.1 Summer 
        </span>
        <span class="groups" id="02\.2hide">
            01.1 Winter    
        </span>
        <span class="groups" id="02\.3hide">
            01.1 Casual skirts
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do believe I need to target somehow text node after labels and make float:left or something?

Comment: You can give float:left to `<a>` and `input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: Shouldn't this `).nextSibling.css(` be this `).next().css(` ?

Comment: With .next().css( it targets next unit not the text node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally pretty hard to deal with text nodes because there are from my count 5 text nodes as immediate children of `.sections`.  Any newline that you use to better format your markup or a misplaced space are examples of text nodes that end up in your markup.  The only way I can think of to target those text nodes is to loop through every child in the `.childNodes` `nodeList` collection of an element and test it against being a text node (which is a `nodeType` of 3).  Even after that you can't directly style the text node.  You have to style a text node's parent in order for it to take effect.  You can wrap that text node in a parent, which is what I recommend doing.  Here is a snippet that does just that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sections, .groups, .units, .classes').each(function(){
        var children = this.childNodes;
        for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
            if(children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && children[i].nodeValue.trim() !== '') {
                var inner = document.createElement('div');

                // preferable to use a class and CSS
                inner.className = 'highlighted';

                // but you can use inline styles too
                inner.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                inner.style.marginLeft = '5px';

                // append it to our div and then insert it before it's original position
                inner.appendChild(children[i]);
                this.insertBefore(inner, children[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The important things to note are that it always checks to see if the trimmed text node is empty.  This avoids grabbing nodes that consist of only new lines, spaces, and the like.  It then wraps the text node in a div that you can either add a class to or style directly (the latter is not recommended).  Also note that I changed the selector.  You can theoretically still select `label` and loop over its parent, but when I tried it didn't work.  For now this snippet uses a selector that just specifies what nodes you want to fetch the children of, not siblings.  Lastly, with the markup you provided, one of the text nodes is inside of a label and is not changed.  This isn't a bug in the javascript.  It doesn't select text nodes that are children of labels.  Changing it to `'.sections, .groups, .units, .classes, label'` would change this.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yh9j5u86/1

Comment: the script you wrote seems to be working and targeting what I exactly need, I just need to figure out now the css to keep text node first line on the same line with input and img  and second line (if text doesn't fit in one) to go along first as it does now but not below image and input. Thank you

Comment: @Christine For that, I would just float the image and checkbox left and add `overflow: auto` to the newly created `div`. http://jsfiddle.net/yh9j5u86/4/ (sorry for the edits... couldn't remember how to `word-wrap: break-word;` :P)